# Independent combined event

Tags: probability

Two athletes, A and B, are attempting to qualify for an international competition in both the 5000m and 10000m races. The probabilities for athlete A, for 5000m is $\frac{3}{5}$ and for 10000m is $\frac{1}{4}$.

For athlete B, for 5000m is $\frac{2}{3}$ and for 10000m is $\frac{2}{5}$.

Assuming that the probabilities are independent, calculate the probability that

a) athlete A will qualify for both races,

b) exactly one of the athletes qualifies for the 5000m race

c) both athletes qualify only for the 10000m race.

For a) $\frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=0.15$

How about b and c? Can anyone give me some hints and explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your result for part a).

Let me do part b) in detail, and give you a hint for part c). In part b), you need exactly one of them to qualify for the $5000$ meter race. This means that you need either $A$ to qualify and $B$ to not qualify, **or** you need $A$ to not qualify and $B$ to qualify, thus getting

$$P(A\text{ qualifies for 5km})P(B\text{ doesn't qualify for 5km}) + P(A\text{ doesn't qualify for 5km})P(B\text{ qualifies for 5km})$$
or
$$\frac{3}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{3}.$$

In part c), you need both athletes to qualify for the 10 km race, **and** you need both of them to *not* qualify for the 5 km race. Pay attention to the word "and" in this problem, as opposed to the highlighted "or" in part b).